# Why Safari 10 bar search is so slow in Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: performance, macos, safari

It seems that one of the surprises with Safari 10 on Mac OS Sierra is that it takes ages to perform a search using the search bar (using Google as default search engine).

It takes on average even more than 5 seconds to open the new search tab with google results.

I would rule out a system issue because I reinstalled the entire OS from scratch less than a week ago. This issue didn't change at all.

The only extensions that I am using are 1Password, LastPas and 1Blocker.

I tried using the search on private mode and it seems to get the same slow results so it should not be related to extensions.

Can I make it 1 second? On Chrome it works well.

Comment: Maybe Safari 10, don't make improvement in performance. I quit Safari 10 for Web Dev, after 1 hour it takes 10Gb out of 8Gb im my MB pro. In another MB air without any inspector open toke 5GB out of 4GB. Yeah more RAM that already installed. Moved to Safari Tech Preview.

Answer (score 6):

Try selecting from the Menu Bar, Safari/Preferences/Search and deselect "Enable Quick Website Search". That appears to have solved some of my issues, although it can still be slow at times.

Answer (score 2):

Menu Bar -> Safari -> Preferences -> Search

Deselect "Preload Top Hit in the background". It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more context to the other answers, below are the official descriptions of the related settings.  I don't care two cents for either of these "features", so I disabled them both, and I saw a significant improvement in search speeds.

> **Enable Quick Website Search** Lets Safari record information about your searches within a website to expedite later searches on that
>   site. You can then search within that website by entering the name of
>   the site, followed by your search term, in the Smart Search field.
>
> Click Manage Websites to see or remove websites for which Safari
>   recorded Quick Website Search information.
>
> **Preload Top Hit in the background** Lets Safari start to load a webpage as soon as it determines a top search hit based on your
>   bookmarks and browsing history.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution! All you need to do is when the Safari is open to open your task manager and find thing called "Safari history", this thing took like 1.7 GB of my Ram and when I've cleaned it by forcing to close the task it never came back after further restarts and my searchar works perfectly like I've just bought this Mac!

Comment: I assume you are talking about `com.apple.Safari.History` in Activity Monitor?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).